# ¿Cómo consumir un WebServices por método GET con Angular?

Tags: java, angularjs, webservice, spring

Acabo de crear un _WebService, el cual expongo a través de [esta página local](http://localhost:8080/demoBancoWeb/controller/transaccionesRest/retirar/String/Int/String). Dicho servicio recibe tres parámetros, dos string y un entero, y en base a eso devuelve una respuesta en formato *JSON* con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "mensaje":"Prueba",
    "saldo": 0
}
```

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo consumir a través de _Angular_por método GET este *WebServices*?

Comment: El lenguaje / plataforma en que está implementado el WS no es importante. El cliente hace una conexión HTTP/S y recibe un contenido en un formato específico, lo que haya detrás da igual si es java, php, perl...

Comment: Eh, ¿has intentado algo? Veo que ya hiciste el recorrido, debes recordar que Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que lo desees armar en un factory o service.

```
    Service.$inject = ['$http'];
    function Service($http){
    var service = this;

    service.get = get;
    return service;


        function get() {
            return $http.get(URL, {cache: true}) // Se puede obviar el cache: true si no se requiere cache
                .then(function (response) {

                    return response;
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    HandleError()
                })
        }
}
```

La url de acuerdo a lo que comentas, podría ser de esta manera:

```
path/to/api?param1=value1&param2=value2&...&param=valueN
```

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando. Saludos.

PD: Te recomendaría de todas maneras que leyeras las reglas en cuanto a la cantidad mínima de información al momento de formular preguntas.